# "supremum" of function plus constant

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

Let $(A,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ a measurable real
function. Define $\text{ess} \sup (f)=\inf\{c\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\mid f\mid>c)=0\}$ and $\text{ess} \inf (f)=\sup\{c\in \mathbb{R}:\mu(\mid f\mid<c)=0\}$.

Show that $\text{ess} \sup (f+c)=\text{ess} \sup (f)+c, \forall c \in \mathbb{R}$.

So far I know that $\text{ess} \sup (f+c)\leq\text{ess} \sup (f)+c$.

Comment: Suppose otherwise. Then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False! If $f=-c$ ($c>0$) then $esssup(f+c)=0$ and $esssup(f)+c=2c$. If you remove absolute value signs in the definition of esssup then the result is true.

Comment: I agree with you!

Comment: With your observation, I conclude that $f\geq g$ does not imply $ess\sup f \geq ess\sup g$ neither $ess\inf f \geq ess\inf g$. Take $f,g:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x)=1/(x+1)$ and $g(x)=-1-1/(x+1)$ (which are measurable functions). Then $f\geq g$ but $ess\sup f<ess\sup g$ and $ess\inf f <ess\inf g$. Do you agree?

Comment: Sure. In all these the only problem is you are looking at upper and lower bounds for $|f|$ instead of bounds for $f$ and that is why these statements become false.